# jspで入力フォームの値を保持したい

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlet

#### 解決したいこと

今Webアプリを作っています。入力フォームに値を保持したいのですが、うまくいきません。
表以外はうまくいったのですが、表の中の入力フォームはうまく値を保持することができませんでした
ネットでも色々調べたのですが、そもそもtableを入力フォームにしている事例があまりなく困っています

#### 発生している問題・エラー

1,2枚目で入力して投稿ボタンを押してエラーがあった場合1,2枚目で入力した値をそのままにしたいのですが3,4枚目のとおりうまくいってません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 該当のソースコード

```java
<form method="POST" action="<c:url value='/purchases/new' />">

    <label for="title">現場名</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="title" value="${purchase.title}" />
    <br />

    <label for="delivery_date">発注日</label><br />
    <input type="date" name="delivery_date" value="${purchase.delivery_date}" />
    <br />

    <label for="desired_delivery_date">納入希望日</label><br />
    <input type="date" name="desired_delivery_date" value="${purchase.desired_delivery_date }" />
    <br />

    <label for="delivery_plase">納品住所</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="delivery_plase" value="${login_orderer.address}" />
    <br /><br />

    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>品番・品名</th>
                <th>数量</th>
                <th>単位</th>
            </tr>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${errorsMap != null }">
                    <c:forEach items="${success }" var="success" varStatus="i">
                        <tr>
                            <c:choose>
                                <c:when test="${success.item != null }">
                                    <td><input type="text" name="items" value="${success.item }"></td>
                                </c:when>
                                <c:otherwise>
                                    <td><input type="text" name="items" value=""></td>
                                </c:otherwise>
                            </c:choose>
                            <td><input type="text" name="volumes"
                                value="${success.volume }" /></td>
                            <td><select name="units">
                                    <option value="m">ｍ</option>
                                    <option value="㎡">㎡</option>
                                    <option value="式">式</option>
                                    <option value="ケース">ケース</option>
                            </select></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
            <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="9">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="items" value=""></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="volumes" value="" /></td>
                <td><select name="units">
                        <option value="m">ｍ</option>
                        <option value="㎡">㎡</option>
                        <option value="式">式</option>
                        <option value="ケース">ケース</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

#### 自分で試したこと

入力フォームで受け取ったものをサーブレットのpostで"items"や"volumes"をListにいれてjspで出力したり
hashmapに入れてみたりpをjspで出力したりいろいろ試した結果サーブレットではなくjspがうまく書けていないのではないかと思っています。

Comment: `success`に値を設定しているコードの抜粋も追記して下さい。

Comment: inputのname属性がほとんど一緒ですけどこれは何か意図があって同じにしていますか？

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://qiita.com/ryo-0213/questions/2954a28207ea689b8cb3

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/294845

Comment: teratailで解決済みの様子